# Implementation of DGIM algorithm in hadoop using python?

Tags: python, java, algorithm, hadoop, data-mining

I am currently in love with working with hadoop clusters...
I am new to this hadoop world
I have worked with hadoop java configuration but as I need to implement with python as well.

From few days I have been trying to implement the dgim algorithm with mapreduce but unable to find out the solution.

Here is my python code of DGIM algorithm.

```
import IPython
import sys
import itertools
import time
import math

def checkAndMergeBucket(bucketList, t):
    bucketListLength = len(bucketList)
    for i in range (bucketListLength):
        if len(bucketList[i]) > 2:
            bucketList[i].pop(0)
            if i + 1 >= bucketListLength:
                bucketList[i].pop(0)
            else:
                bucketList[i+1].append(bucketList[i].pop(0))

K = 1000
N = 1000
k = int(math.floor(math.log(N, 2)))
t = 0
onesCount = 0
bucketList = []
for i in range(k+1):
    bucketList.append(list())

with open('engg5108_stream_data.txt') as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            for i in range(k+1):
                for j in range(len(bucketList[i])):
                    print "Size of bucket: %d, timestamp: %d" % (pow(2,i), bucketList[i][j])
                    earliestTimestamp = bucketList[i][j]    
            for i in range(k+1):
                for j in range(len(bucketList[i])):
                    if bucketList[i][j] != earliestTimestamp:
                        onesCount = onesCount + pow(2,i)
                    else:
                        onesCount = onesCount + 0.5 * pow(2,i)
            print "Number of ones in last %d bits: %d" % (K, onesCount)
            break
        t = (t + 1) % N
        for i in range(k+1):
            for bucketTimestamp in bucketList[i]:
                if bucketTimestamp == t:
                    bucketList[i].remove(bucketTimestamp)
        if c == '1':
            bucketList[0].append(t)
            checkAndMergeBucket(bucketList, t)
        elif c == '0':
            continue
```

As Its working correct with this output as,

```
Size of bucket: 1, timestamp: 0
Size of bucket: 2, timestamp: 992
Size of bucket: 2, timestamp: 997
Size of bucket: 4, timestamp: 990
Size of bucket: 8, timestamp: 969
Size of bucket: 8, timestamp: 984
Size of bucket: 16, timestamp: 955
Size of bucket: 32, timestamp: 917
Size of bucket: 64, timestamp: 729
Size of bucket: 64, timestamp: 856
Size of bucket: 128, timestamp: 597
Size of bucket: 256, timestamp: 341
Number of ones in last 1000 bits: 457
```

Well Problem is how can i implement in form of mapreduce?
Feel free to answer in Java and python.

Edit: Here is bits of stream save this as " engg5108_stream_data.txt "

```
1100001011000010100001001001101000100011011111111111100111111101100010000010111100010110100010011011001101001011111101101011100110011111101000110101010100111011000001010010000010011111001100100110111000100110001111110000110111001010101101101011011000001110001001101000001100111100001000101110000100001111010000000111101001000101000001010101110110111100110001001000000110010001010001100010111001111010100101010111101010000010001001111101110000000010111100011100110010000011011001010111110011100000001111101110101010001001000011001011111010100101001111010111110110010100000100111001001111101111110100010110111011001011111111100111010000111000011011111110101111111010111011010010011010101010010001000000111110111111110100101100001100011101100110100011000000010000010010101110001010001100011010001101111000111001101010000101010010100011000110011101110111110010011000111000011111001011100001101100111000100101100101110011000010110010001110100111101110011101000001011110110011000101010111100111110100001011001001100001001010100110100001000000110111010010111010100001110101101110110000110011100100000100010110100010101010110011000010110110101001101010011111011001010101010010001101111000001100101101011101101110000110011100110000110001111100001100110011101011100110011001100000001010010010010001001000011111010001111100100000001011001101010000001000010010111100011000101011100000001010010101000111100011110100100100001101101011000001110010010110001010000101011000110100101000100100011000110000110100110011001001101111011011100110010100110011110111010111001010100000110100001111111010110101100111001111000100010011010100101101011011111100001100000011010000001111010101100001001111111101011101011111111110011111101101010010110011001100001101101100100101010010100001111000111101100011110100100110011110010100100011010011110100000000011000101111000000011000100110111110011101100111000101010111001101100001010100101000000001000010110111000010001110100010001100000111010010010100010010101000000000010010101101100001100010000100111010110111110010111011101001000110111000111111000000000010010101010010000101011011001001010110010000001100000110101010101011000010001100110000000110101010101011101101010101101011010100010011100011100101101010000100110001101110111010111111101111101000000000100111000100001100001010111001000010000110011000010100100011001110011010000101011010011010011000110000101110101010011000101001011101011110110000001001000011110001101001010101000000000011101011010001100010000101001100001100101111110010110111010101001010100010010101101000110101101011001101110001110101110000001010001001010111001111110011110111111011100111000000100101100100011011111101101011010011000001110110000110101010011101010010100010000100111011101000111111111110100111100000110011100110011111111111010111010010111001100000010001100100011101010110000100100010111101010101100001011101101000001110110010000111111101000100101000001011111010110010110111100101111001001111000001101010010110110011111101000100000000111100101101000001100000110110110010100000001000101110111010001101000000100011010100100110011001000100010011111001011011001011001101100011101000110101110000001101100010010010010111101010001010010011110010010010111001100011010000000001000010010100100101011100110100110110001010011010000100100101000111001100000000110101110101101101111000100101101100101101100001110011001001101100001111001110001100100111110010000100110100010010000101011010110110101101011111011011100001101111111001010000010111111010111110000011110110100000110000001001111110000001111011111000100101010101011011001111100100100011101000011100001101000110010111000100111010100011011000001100101011011110101111010110110110001001011111001100011011110001011110000010101000000000000111101010101100111000100011101111001100011100010101011001101101010000100100110001001001011001010101000011110011110001100011111111000110101101111011111100101110011011010100000111000110000110000011000111111000101001111110111000010011110010011100000000101001101101001110001100010101101111011100101000011011001111010110101110010010111011100111110100100100011101010101010001100000110111100111100010000011110111011011100000110101011000000011010001111110101000001110101110101001000001001010001101000000011010101110000110111000001000111110101110011100010000011011001101101100010010011001110100000011111110110100010010101101000101100011101110110011010100011011110101110000110110111000101100110000010101011111010100000010001111001000110101110010100011110110110001111101111010000001001110111111001000011110101111110001000011111100100010100010111000110010010111010100101111100000100101100011101011110010010010110100011011101011110001010101000011111010011001111111101110100011101000110000110011100001110011011011010001100000011001001100000101111010101001100010011010101110000001010001000111010000001100101001010010010100010000101101011011001111111111111010010011101011000111010010100110000110101101011110110000001010001111101001101001000010000000000001010011010101010101110001000011010001101011010000101110000010000000111010111111000000111000101100011100000000100010011011011111100011111101011110001001101111000011010000111001001011001011101010100001100000001100001011111010001100011010010100010111111110011111101101101110110000010010010111001001100110100110101001110111110101010101001101101100110010111111110101111000110101111110010011010011001000111100110000000010110010011100110111110000101111110011000100001110110100010100010000110110101010101000000000100001000100100100100010001101101000001101001010101001110010110101110000111010011010100111000101011111101000100110111010011100000010110011001111011011101010110000011100000101100010110011101111101101001100101100111001110011000101011011011111111011111000101110110001001111110110011101000001011101110111010000110100110100010010110100100100000000110100110001110111010010101111011011000100100100101010010111001010000101101000010101110000000101010101001101100000001000100010011101111010100101010100011011000110111011110011010100110100101011010101011100111010100111100111111001100100011111100101101101001010000111011111101101001110100001011111111001011111111100000010100100111101101111001101101010001001001000000000100011010010100100011101000100111101001101000100110110100001101110000011101000101010100111010000100011011110010110001101010111101000101101100000010011100000001101111000101010011010101000010111010111101000000001100010110000000000011111010101110010101100010001010110110001111010111011001010011001000010101010010110001000111110110110001100011010000101101011011011001011011000010011001001010100100110111010001101011100100011000110101000010011110111100110110011100011101101100111110011100111000101001010100010010001101000010100111010111111011111101011110011010001001010110110001101000110010001100000100001100110000111000010010101110000110011001001010000000000110100110000100011110110110010100011000100000010011110100000001100001101010011101011110111110001010011101011111101000101011111001111011011110101010101010000110000011010111000110001110000101010101000101101010001111111111011010111110111010010010011101111110101111100001010101100010110000010101000001011101001000001100001010111010101110101000010000001010011011100101010001110111011110010101010010111101011110101100001011101111100101001000011100010010000011011100000001010001110010101111011111010000100011100011101111000111001010010000101101111100001011101000000010101100011100000101001101100100111001110100010001000101001111010001000001010101001100101111101110000000110010000101000011101101110111101110100010000011010001111111010010100101000101001100111100001011100010000110101010100111101001110111100010001111000111110101001011111000010011100100000001100000001000110110011001110010011010100000010100000000010011111001110000001011000101010100110100110010001010100011110011110000111001000001111110110101000001110001011011011101011100111110111101011000110110010110111101110110000110000000010111010100000001111101000001100100001110101000101110011111101110010100011111011000001111010101010110001001011010100000011101001111000100001100100010101110111111010001101011110001100110111100111110011011111100001111110101111010010100100010101000111101001100111001100101100100011010101011100111010110111011010001110010111111001100010111111010000011110011010100101101101110111011100001001001100010001000101111111111100001100000110111101010110111101111001101011100000001010011011010011100000011111010101000011011111011101100111001100101100101001101010111101101100000010100000110111010011000100010000011101110000110011101011111111001101000001010111110110011000001001001010001101111110011001001011100101010010111001101000010100101101100011111000001010111001011111101101110011100001110000001101001110010001100000100110010100000001000010000000010000011100011101010100010001100010111001011010110101010001101100011001011010110100010011000011101111010110101111010110110111110000111010001001111110011111101001110000110000000110110001011111100101001001111000101110010111101000010110101101110011001111000001101110111010111001100110111010011100101000111001100101100110111111001000101010111010111100011110010010010101001110011101011001001001101010011110101001100100110100110101010001111110100001111101100000010111011111011100011000001110000110001110010011111110101001101111111101111011101101101100010101000010001001100010111111111111110101111101010000011011110001111001010011011001111100111110011011111001010110010010000101111111000110011001000100111101000110100100110101010001111101000111111010011110000010101001110100110001001011010000010001011100110011100111101000011010010000000010001010101010110101100001010110100000010110001100010001000100100011110101011011110110100100110010101111111010100111110000000111001000011101011011100011100000101110100101000001000110011011010010111100110010001001110000010010111100100110101011010110101110101111111000011101011101001011110011000110011010000111011100001011111101000001101001000101010000111110100011010100001010001101110111000111100001111100111100101001
```

Comment: @BenWatson thanks for your answer I will surely try with Spark .

Comment: You could also just try Dask or the new Pandas/Spark integration if you really are just  asking about parallelizing your code. Otherwise, it's unclear what your "map" or "reduce" step(s) are here